# Weak references not dropping value

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm writing a test to ensure that the `Drop` impl of a value released onto the javascript world runs after it's garbage collected, but I cannot get it to work:

```rust
wasm_bindgen_test::wasm_bindgen_test_configure!(run_in_browser);

#[wasm_bindgen_test]
fn test_drop() {
    static DROPPED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

    struct SetOnDrop;
    impl Drop for SetOnDrop {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            let is_dropped = DROPPED.swap(true, atomic::Ordering::AcqRel);
            assert!(!is_dropped);
        }
    }
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    struct WasmSetOnDrop(SetOnDrop);

    let value = WasmSetOnDrop(SetOnDrop);
    let value = JsValue::from(value);

    js_sys::eval("window.gc()").expect("Unable to call `window.gc`");
    assert!(!DROPPED.load(atomic::Ordering::Acquire), "Value was dropped early");

    mem::drop(value);

    js_sys::eval("window.gc()").expect("Unable to call `window.gc`");
    assert!(DROPPED.load(atomic::Ordering::Acquire), "Value was not dropped");
}
```

I'm running this inside of a test, with `WASM_BINDGEN_WEAKREF=1 WASM_BINDGEN_EXTERNREF=1 wasm-pack test --chrome --headless`.

Unfortunately, it panics at the last assert, with `DROPPED` being `false`.

I believe that with weak references, this code should work as-is, but I assume the value that I released into javascript is somehow being kept alive by the wasm glue code?

I've also tried:

- Creating a `Vec<u8>` / `JsArray` and pushing several megabytes of data before calling the garbage collector.
- Calling `window.gc` on a loop until `DROPPED` became true, but the test ran for several minutes without proceeding.